# Django - how to disable Referer check

Tags: django, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have put a Django-based web project (Cloudera Hue: https://github.com/cloudera/hue) behind nginx used for load balancing and SSL offloading.

Getting stuck on 403 error with CSRF error.
Log file contains

> 5:32:32 PM    WARNING access
> 10.170.3.21 -anon- - "POST /accounts/login/ HTTP/1.1" -- Referer checking failed -
> https://hue-dev.discover.abc.com/hue/accounts/login/?next=/ does not
> match https://hue-dev.discover.abc.com:443/.

**Is there is a way to disable Referer check in a Django project?**

Referer check doesn't add any security as Referer in http header can be easily spoofed. https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/66165/does-referrer-header-checking-offer-any-real-world-security-improvement

I already have following in nginx.conf

```
  proxy_set_header        Host $host;

  proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Server $host;
```

and also tried following changes regarding Referer http attribute:

1. `proxy_pass_header       Referer`
2. `proxy_hide_header       Referer`
3. `proxy_set_header        $http_referer`

all of these options produce the same CSRF/Referer check error in Django/Hue backend.

Again, for me it would be just easier to disable Referer check in Django.

If it's not possible, then the issue is probably in Django code here:
https://github.com/django/django/blob/22e8ab02863819093832de9f771bf40a62a6bd4a/django/middleware/csrf.py#L280

`referer` variable there is a urlparse object (see https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html ) which contains "netloc" property with a `port`.

Notice the error again - `netloc`s don't match because one has a port (443) and another doesn't have it (443 port is default for https):

> Referer checking failed -
>
> https://hue-dev.discover.abc.com/hue/accounts/login/?next=/
> does not match
> https://hue-dev.discover.abc.com:443/.

so I guess it should be some sort of `Referer` field transformation made in nginx config to cut out `443` port explicitly (or add it).

Also posted Django bug here - https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30017
but I guess there still could be a check do disable Referer check in Django, or
at least redact Referer to cut/add port 443 for https through nginx configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing `https://hue-dev.discover.abc.com:443/` because of the following line in your nginx config:

```
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
```

You already have `X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme` in your config to specify the protocol, so it should be safe to use `X-Forwarded-Host $host` instead. That should fix your issue.

Another option, if you ignore the above, is to add `hue-dev.discover.abc.com:443` to `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` in your django settings.

As for your original question, there is no way to disable django's referer check in your situation. See [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/22e8ab02863819093832de9f771bf40a62a6bd4a/django/middleware/csrf.py#L242).

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this issue through setting a static Referer with port 443 embedded in the URL

`proxy_set_header              Referer https://hue-dev.discover.abc.com:443/;`

Although I like @nebuler's answer better.

Still hoping that this bug could be fixed in Django.
Their referer check thinks that `https://www.com` and `https://www.com:443` are too different things. `https` has default port 443 so those are the same thing.